# How can I send an XMPP message using the command-line?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, xmpp

What options are available on Ubuntu 14.04 to send XMPP (Jabber) messages using a command-line client?

Background: I want to configure XMPP notifications for my Icinga server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `sendxmpp` for that, here's a link to the manpage:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sendxmpp.1p.html

#### Example

```
echo "hello bob!" | sendxmpp -s hello someone@jabber.org
```

Comment: I'm accepting the answer because in theory it should work. Unfortunately my XMPP server uses SSL and `sendxmpp --ssl -n` fails with some "Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/XML/Stream.pm line 763" error.

Comment: I'm finding `sendxmpp` really unreliable. It's also complicated too - as I'm having to use odd combinations of flags just to get it to work!

Answer (score 4):

Found a somewhat hidden tool that also works for my XMPP server with SSL:

The `lm-send-async.c` example which comes with [libloudmouth1-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libloudmouth1-dev) package allows to send XMPP messages. But one has to compile it first:

```
cp -av /usr/share/doc/libloudmouth1-dev/examples/lm-send-async.c.gz .
gunzip lm-send-async.c.gz
gcc -o lm-send-async lm-send-async.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs loudmouth-1.0`
```

Send a message:

```
./lm-send-async --server bar.net --username foo@bar.net --password F00BAR \
 --fingerprint "11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88:99:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF:00:11:22:33:44" \
 --recipient friend@bar.net --message "Hello World!"
```

Comment: I get an error when attempting to install that package :-/